# Dynamic reference in a .net core app targeting net standard 1.6?

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-core, .net-standard-1.6

I'm trying to use a `dynamic` variable in a C# .net core app that's targeting .net standard 1.6. (platform? library? framework? meta-framework?)  I first encountered this problem in a real application, but I have reduced it to a minimal reproduction.

### project.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": { "emitEntryPoint": true },
    "dependencies": { "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0" },
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": { "imports": "dnxcore50" }
    },
    "runtimes": { "win10-x64": {} }
}
```

### Program.cs

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        dynamic hello = "hello world";
        Console.WriteLine(hello);
    }
}
```

When I try to build this, I'm getting a build error on `Console.WriteLine(hello);` saying this.

> CS0656    Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

Is it possible to use `dynamic` variables in an application targeting netstandard 1.6?  How?

Comment: If it helps, targeting `netcoreapp1.0` (that's also supporting `netstandard 1.6`) fixes the error. That's weird.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Add [System.Dynamic.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Dynamic.Runtime/) and [Microsoft.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CSharp/) as dependencies.

Comment: I ended up having to add the following dependencies and versions: "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "4.0.11", "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1", "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR": "1.0.4".  It's able to build and run now.

Comment: `Microsoft.CSharp` depends on `System.Dynamic.Runtime`, so you don't need to add both.

Comment: @recursive: I concur. I had to add all three of these as well. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it's a .NET Standard project?

Answer (score 32):

Right-click the project > Manage NuGet Packages... > Add the following two highlighted packages:
[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue. I am running .net core 2.1 (or 2.2... same issue). I only needed to add Microsoft.CSharp.

Answer (score 7):

If you're writing an application, not a library, you should use `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, not `NETStandard.Library` and `netcoreapp1.0`, not `netstandard1.6`. Doing that would fix your issue.

If you want to use `dynamic` in a library (or application that does not depend on `Microsoft.NETCore.App`), you need to add `Microsoft.CSharp` as a dependency.

Comment: Is there an authoritative reference for which "frameworks" should be used for which purposes?  I've been looking for information on what all this means, and all I find are contradictory blogs and similar.  What's your source for this information?

Comment: For a start, that's what the project.json produced by `dotnet new -t console` and `dotnet new -t lib` produce. For more explanation, see [the article *Packages, Metapackages and Frameworks* in .Net docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages), specifically [the section on Package-based Frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages#package-based-frameworks).